# Why are the expressions of the Skyrme Model related with a kinetic and a mass term?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, group-theory, skyrmion

I was reading about the Syrme Model Lagrangian,
$$
\mathcal{L} =-f^2_\pi/4 Tr(L_\mu L^\mu) + 1/32e^2 Tr([L_\mu,L_\nu]^2)- \frac{\mu^2}{2} Tr(1-U) 
$$
where $L_\mu=U^\dagger \partial_\mu U$. I've read that $Tr(L_\mu L^\mu)$ is the kinetic term and $\frac{\mu^2}{2} Tr(1-U) $ is the mass term, however i don't see why. I tried to introduce the field expression
$$
U = \sigma (x) + i \boldsymbol{\pi}(x) \boldsymbol{\tau}
$$
to see what happens but I don't obtain any satisfactory result.

Edit: In particular, I was hoping to find something that would highlight the relationship of those terms with the kinetic energy and mass of the skyrmion. However introducing U in $L_\mu L^\mu$ I obtain
$$
L_\mu  = \sigma \partial_\mu \sigma +i(\sigma \partial_\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}-\boldsymbol{\pi} \partial_\mu \sigma)\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau} + \mathcal{O}(\boldsymbol{\pi}^2)
$$
so
$$
L_\mu L^\mu = \sigma^2 \partial_\mu\sigma \partial^\mu \sigma  + i \sigma \partial_\mu \sigma(\sigma \partial^\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}-\boldsymbol{\pi} \partial^\mu \sigma)\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}+i(\sigma \partial_\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}-\boldsymbol{\pi} \partial_\mu \sigma)\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau} \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma  - (\sigma \partial_\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}-\boldsymbol{\pi} \partial_\mu \sigma)\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau} (\sigma \partial^\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}-\boldsymbol{\pi} \partial^\mu \sigma)\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}
$$
so there is a $\sigma^2 \partial_\mu \boldsymbol{\pi}\partial^\mu \boldsymbol{\pi} $ which I may associate with a kinetik term of mesons but it appears with a $\sigma^2$, moreover there are a lot of other terms that I cannot dismiss.

Comment: Maybe you should show your "unsatisfactory results".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.